# Selenium:How to open chrome extension with selenium/or login to chrome extension

Tags: java, selenium

Task: emulate login to chrome extension via selenium.

Lets take any extension, which requires login.
We can add it to selenium test eg with next code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("path to user dir") + "path to chrome driver exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(System.getProperty("path to user dir") + "path to extension crx file"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

but there is a trouble - we should login to this extension, to continue work.
(for example any crypto wallet, like iostwallet on jpg example)

[image]

So, how to press extension button and enter credentials, using selenium methods?

Comment: Please check https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium/

Comment: thanks! will go through, and if success, will shortly describe recipe

Comment: Thank you so much. Waiting for your reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer in proposed by @amy blog. Thanks mate!

If in short, we can do in following way:

1) View source of needed extension:

```
- download crx of needed extension
- get extension unique ID (just on extension page in "details")
- view it source, eg using "extension source viewer" extension
- note page You need (e.g. "index.html")
```

2)Now we have url of page we need to source, eg

```
chrome-extension://<extension unique ID>/index.html
```

and we can easily navigate on the page using selenium, eg

```
driver.get(config.getProperty("extensionpageurl"));
driver.findelement(....).<actions>;
...
```